# Add to model in form, then redisplay form to add more

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to MVC3, but so far I have managed to get along with my code just great.

Now, I would like to make a simple form, that allows the user to input a text string, representing the name of an employee.  I would then like this form to be submitted and stored in my model, in a sort of list.  The form should then re-display, with a for-each loop writing out my already added names.  When I'm done and moving on, I need to store this information to my database.

What I can't figure out, is how to store this temporary information, until i push it to my database. Pushing everytime I submit I can do, but this has cause me alot of headaches.

Hope you guys see what I'm trying to do, and have an awesome solution for it. :)

This is a simplified version of what I've been trying to do:

**Model**

```
public class OrderModel
{
    public virtual ICollection<Employees> EmployeesList { get; set; }

    public virtual Employees Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employees
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model OrderModel
@{
    if (Model.EmployeesList != null)
    {
        foreach (var c in Model.EmployeesList)
        {
            @c.Name<br />
        }
    }
}
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Employees.Name)

    <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(OrderModel model)
{
    model.EmployeesList.Add(model.Employees);
    // This line gives me the error: "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should handle this by burning the employee list into the page. Right now, you're not giving your form any way of recognizing the list.

In an EditorTemplates file named Employees:

```
@model Employees

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name);
```

In your view:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.EmployeesList)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Employees.Name)

    <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(OrderModel model)
{
   if (model.EmployeesList == null)
      model.EmployeesList = new List<Employees>();

    model.EmployeesList.Add(model.Employees);
    return View(model);
}
```

As an added bonus to this method, it would be easy to add ajax so the user never has to leave the page when they add new employees (You might be able to just insert a new hidden value with javascript and avoid ajax. It would depend on if you do anything other than add to your list in your post).

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be a good use for **TempData**.  You can store anything in there, kind of like the cache, but unlike the cache it only lasts until the next request.  To implement this, change the action method like this (example only):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(OrderModel model)
{
    dynamic existingItems = TempData["existing"];
    if (existingItems != null) 
    {
        foreach (Employee empl in existingItems)
            model.EmployeesList.Add(empl );
    }
    model.EmployeesList.Add(model.Employees);
    TempData["existing"] = model.EmployeesList;
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I get the "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error on the "model.EmployeesList.Add(model.Employees);" just as i did before. I forgot to mention this in the question.

Comment: @holaq, that's no doubt because the model.EmployeesList is null after the postback.  I updated my answer to create it.  (Although since I'm not familiar with ICollection, I'm not sure if my syntax works.)

Comment: This would work, only thing is if you refresh the page the employee list would disappear.

Comment: @AFinkelstein If you refresh the page after a post, then it would re-post.  If you're worried about someone re-navigating to the page, you can always use TempData.Keep() inside the [Get] method-- that retains all the TempData until the next request.

Comment: @dbaseman ...Actually that would work, wouldn't it. +1 for a solution that never would have occurred to me. That said, using temp data for something like this still seems peculiar to me. I'd been taught to avoid temp data whenever possible.

Comment: It seems i can't have two accepted answers, cause this deserved it too. This approach helped me out in a different scenario. You guys are the best! Thanks.